# Get user's current Lat Long using Places API

Tags: android, geolocation

Is it possible to get user's current Lat Long using Places API, instead of Maps API? I'm sure there's a process that involves user's current Lat Long but is it possible to get them?

Currently I'm creating activities that use Places API, and now I need user's current Lat Long, I think it's not worth to add Maps API only for that function.

Comment: You don't need either.  Use the built in LocationManager, or use FusedLocationProvider.  Neither of the other two APIs are needed for just getting location.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to fetch only the Lat Long of the current location, then you don't need to use any Api. You may follow the below tutorial to implement it without using Place Api
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

If you still want to use Place Api then you need to use `Places.PlacesDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace` method to create a `PendingIntent` that returns with a `PlaceLikelihoodBuffer`. First define the GoogleApiClient and use the below code to fetch the location -

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace( mGoogleApiClient, null );
result.setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult( PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces ) {

         PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood = likelyPlaces.get( 0 );
         String content = "";
         if( placeLikelihood != null && placeLikelihood.getPlace() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty( placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName() ) )
             content = "Most likely place: " + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng()+ "\n";
        if( placeLikelihood != null )
            content += "Percent change of being there: " + (int) ( placeLikelihood.getLikelihood() * 100 ) + "%";
        mTextView.setText( content );

        likelyPlaces.release();
    }
});
```

For more info, refer to this article - https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/google-play-services-using-the-places-api--cms-23715